# Why Does $\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

> We defined $$\cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$$
>   Because $cos(x)$ set values on the $\mathbb{R}$, and due to a theorem, there can be at most one analytic function which get the same values on $\mathbb{R}$

This was on the lecture notes, what does it mean? that if there are 2 analytic functions which agree on $\mathbb{R}$ they will agree on the whole $\mathbb{C}$ plane?

Comment: If two holomorphic functions agree on a converging sequence (or on $\mathbb{R}$) the identity theorem yields that they have to be the same.

Comment: @MundronSchmidt ok. but it does not explain why $cos(z)=\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ just why there is one function and not two?

Comment: This equation can be concluded from the famous Euler-DeMoivre-equation $e^{it}=\cos(t)+\sin(t)i$.

Comment: Or you use the power series of the exponential function and apply $x=iz$. You can see that $e^{iz}+e^{-iz}$ has the same power series as $2\cos(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

If that's a *definition*, then there's nothing to worry about: take it or leave it.

However it is *justified* defining this function over $\mathbb{C}$, because for real $z$ we have
$$
\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\cos z
$$
according to the standard definition of cosine over $\mathbb{R}$ and Euler’s formulas.

The identity theorem tells us that any entire function with the same property (evaluating as the cosine on the real numbers) *must* be the same.

**Identity theorem.** *Two complex analytic functions that are defined on the same domain and that coincide on a subset having a limit point are equal.*

If you work out the Taylor series about $0$ of the given expression, you easily find
$$
\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
which is another way for seeing that we are justified in stating the above definition.

For the same reason it is justified defining
$$
e^z=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}
$$
even if in the left-hand side there is no exponentiation when $z$ is not real. The notation $e^z$ is not ambiguous when $z$ is real. By the mentioned identity theorem, that's the only way for extending the exponential function from the real numbers to a *holomorphic* (*analytic*) function over the complex plane.

Comment: Hey, where you wrote you can easily find that $e^{iz} + e^{-iz}$ is 2 times the Taylor series for cosine, I am having trouble because we know $e^{iz}$ is just the sum from $0$ to infinity of $\frac{i^nz^n}{n!}$, and for $e^{-iz}$ its the same but we have the $(-1)^n$ term, when we take a product I get everything except I am stuck with $i^{2n}$ How do I pull this out to be just 2?

Comment: @HossienSahebjame Note that $i^{2n}=(-i)^{2n}=\begin{cases} -1 & \text{$n$ odd} \\ 1 & \text{$n$ even}\end{cases}$